# Setting Up Formula

Tags: excel, installation, formula

I am trying to setup an invoice in Excel. I have attached an image of the table setup. The Total column should have the following equation from the corresponding cells but I am having trouble getting it to work.

```
8500 x 0.0153 = 130.05
130.05 x .13 = 16.9
130.05 + 16.9 = 146.96 <---Amount that should be displayed in the total column
```

In other words

1. B10*C10=Total1
2. Total1*D10=Total2
3. Total1+Total2

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use parentheses, and simplify the math:

```
=(B10 *C10) * (1 + D10)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I don't know why i was overthinking that.